# How to calculate scalar neutron flux

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering, neutrons

I am really confused about the difference between flux and scalar flux. I have a specific question:

If we have a parallel neutron beam of strength $\phi_0$ given in neutrons/cm$^2$s, incident on a finite slab of thickness $L$, consisting of a purely absorbing material with cross section $\Sigma_a (x)$ and the neutrons only travel from left to right in the slab, how do I find the scalar flux?  Do I merely divide $\phi_0/\Sigma_a$? That would give me a result in neutrons per second, right?  I think this might have to do something with the neutron attenuation, but can't seem to get on the right track with this problem.

Comment: $\phi/\Sigma_a$ does not seem a thing. Normally you multiply $\phi/Sigma_a$ to get number of events occurring, depending on what type of event $\Sigma_a$ represents.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that *angular momentum flux* $\psi$ depends on the direction and *scalar momentum flux* does not, because is integrated over all directions:
$\phi = \int_{4\pi} \psi d\Omega$.

For the rest, they exhibit the same dependence on Energy. So $\psi$ gives the amount of neutrons that at a certain position $\bf r$ and at energy $E$ are moving in the direction $\hat \Omega$. While $\phi$ reflects the amount of neutrons that at a certain position $\bf r$ and at energy $E$ are moving in any direction.